# In best case how can I check a link belongs to *.domain.com?

Tags: javascript

How can I check a link belongs to a domain *.domain.com using javascript?

I mean that I ignore subdomain.

Comment: What do you mean by _link belongs to a domain_? Do you mean the href points to a domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are talking about links on the page (`<a>` elements), then try this:

```
// regular expression to check for domain.com
// won't match tricky ones like domain.company.com nodomain.com :)
var re = /(^|\.)domain\.com(\/|$)/i; 

// loop through all the links
$("a").each(function() {
  // test if href attribute belongs to domain.com
  if(re.test($(this).attr('href'))) {
    // do what you want with links that belong to domain.com
    $(this).addClass("domaincom");
  }
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/ehuwor/6/edit#javascript,html,live)** is the code.

Comment: Actually, to be picky, your code isn't completely right. `.com` should be `\.com`, to escape the period; otherwise, it's treated as a "match-all" regex.

Comment: @mc10 Ooops, you are 140% right :). I updated my answer. Thanks!